# helloworld doesn't appear when adding my code

Tags: python, google-app-engine

i'm making a little app that runs two threads for ever. I took "hello world" example from https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld
(which worked fine for me by itself) and just added it my code:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        q1 = Queue()
        q2 = Queue()

        cs = Thread(target=Control_service.control_service_d, args=[q1,q2])
        cs.setDaemon(True)

        m = Thread(target=Machine.machine_d, args=[q2])
        m.setDaemon(True)

        cs.start()
        m.start()

        time.sleep(6)
        q1.put(Control_service.requestObj('ravit',0))

        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),], debug=True)
```

I see from my printings inside the two threads that they work ok, but I can't see the hello world any more when getting to localhost:8080

what the problem with my code ?

thanks

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is right? It looks like your `get()` method is not properly indented.

Comment: Indentation is probably right, or else OP would be getting an invalid Syntax @DavidReeve

Comment: indentation is right

Comment: A bit late with this comment, but it may be that daemon threads don't work the same way on GAE and you actually need to use a BackgroundThread to spawn a thread which outlives the request: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/background_thread